# ZenDesk chat integration

Tags: integration, zendesk

I am looking at integrating zendesk chat with a web application. The end user is already logged in to the web application so I don't want them to have to enter their details into the chat window. Is there a way to do this with the Zendesk chat widget? Or has anyone does something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can identify users using the `identify` command.

Once you are sure that the `zE` variable is defined, you can use it like that:

```js
if (typeof zE !== 'undefined'){
  zE('webWidget', 'identify', {
    name: userName,
    email: userEmail
  });
}
```

You can find more information in the official documentation here: https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/widget/core#identify.

Comment: hey there, what if we have different users in same domain in same browser? When I identify one, in another tab in another subdomain user will have the same name. Any solution to that?

Comment: @ozan-mudul I have no idea, something similar happened to me: the department configuration wasn't updated when changing domain, because the Zendesk account is the same. I had to clear the cookies to make sure the new configuration was loaded, but I wouldn't know how to manage it at a code level

Comment: I contacted with zendesk, seems like we need to use jwt token auth for that :/ Since it is a lot of work for this simple task, we delayed it but if we do it, I will share the results. I don't know if it will work though